# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'read') in gitlab

Tags: javascript, gitlab

i am bit confused with **TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'read') in gitlab** . I want the follow :

the function
createCalculator () returns an object with three methods:

read (arr) accepts a table of numbers and saves it in its field
object.

sum () returns the sum of the table values

mul () returns the product of the table values

Take the following peace of code :

```
function createCalculator() {

    let calculator = {
        sum() {
            return this.a + this.b + this.c ;

        },

        mul() {
            return this.a * this.b*this.c;

        },

        read(arr) {
            this.a = 1;
            this.b = 3;
            this.c = 6;
            arr.push(arr);

        }
    };

    calculator.read([1,3,6]);
    console.log( calculator.sum() );
    console.log( calculator.mul() );


}
let calculator;
calculator = createCalculator();
```

Comment: Your function doesn't return anything and your read method does not save any array, just assigns some hard coded properties.

Comment: how can i fix it? You can help me?

Comment: What does this have to do with GitLab? Is this happening in some CI pipeline? This seems unrelated to GitLab.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for this, not sure why and when you got your error though (don't understand what this has to do with gitlab).

```js
function createCalculator() {

    return {
        sum() {
          return this.values.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
        },

        mul() {
          return this.values.reduce((a, b) => a * b, 1);
        },

        read(arr) {
          this.values = arr;
        }
    };
}

const calculator = createCalculator();
calculator.read([1,3,6]);
console.log( calculator.sum() );
console.log( calculator.mul() );
```

You could also use a class to do the same thing:

```js
class Calculator {
  static sum() {
    return this.values.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
  }

  static mul() {
    return this.values.reduce((a, b) => a * b, 1);
  }

  static read(arr) {
    this.values = arr;
  }
}

Calculator.read([1,3,6]);
console.log( Calculator.sum() );
console.log( Calculator.mul() );
```

Comment: @mixalispetros still having the issue?